# How to remove line feed from this code?

Tags: perl

I have followin code in one legacy script:

```
while (<FPTR>)  # While still input lines in the file...
{
  if($_ =~ /\x1b&d@
/)
  {
    $aa=$_;
    $aa =~ s/\x1b&d@
/
\x1b&d@/;
    print STDOUT $aa;
  }
...
}
```

Could you please explain - what doe this code do and how to replace it with correct code?
I do not like that there is a line feed in "if" and "=~".
Is it possible to change this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the [INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) has not been redefined, the newline can probably be replaced by `$`.  Then, you should be able to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the copy of the input line to remove the newline. Then prepend `\n` to the output.

```
while (<FPTR>)  # While still input lines in the file... 
{ 
  if (/\x1b&d@$/) { 
    $aa = $_; 
    chomp $aa;
    print STDOUT "\n" . $aa;
  } 
... 
}
```

This would simplify the code by eliminating multiple copies of your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the line feeds with `\n`. See the section on escape sequences in ['Quote and Quote-like operators'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in perldoc perlop.

The `$` metacharacter can also be used. From [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
  $ Match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)
```

Answer (score 0):

That code seems to look for a byte sequence followed by newline and swapping the newkline in front of the pattern. You can use `\n` for the newline (pr `\r\n` if the script is in DOS format), the follwoing is equivalent I think:

```
while (<FPTR>)  # While still input lines in the file...
{
  if($_ =~ m/\x1b&d@\n/)
  {
    $aa=$_;
    $aa =~ s/\x1b&d@\n/\n\x1b&d@/;
    print STDOUT $aa;
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing a chomp() first before processing

```
while (<FPTR>) {
  chomp;
  ....
}
```

Comment: But the chomp is only needed if the line ends with `ESC & d @`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one:

```
/\x1b&d@
/
```

That's the escape character followed by '&d@' at the end of the line. Therefore, I might actually use:

```
while (my $line = <FPTR>) {
    if ( $line =~ /x1b&d@$/ ) {
        chomp $line;
        print $line;
    }
}
```

I do not see why there is a need to make a copy of `$_` in `$aa`, but if that really is necessary, use

```
if ( (my $copy = $line) =~ /x1b&d@$/ ) {
        chomp $copy;
        print $copy;
    }
}
```

You only need to specify `STDOUT` as the filehandle if some other filehandle has been selected as the default.